# Composer autoload - Class not found exception

Tags: php, composer-php, autoloader

I am pulling my hairs out on this one, and that does not happen frequently.

I am trying to use composers autoloader, with a directory of mine. The autoloader works perfectly with another directory.

I am using the following filestructure

```
-Root
 | application
   | Module
      | Users
         | Users.php
```

The Users.php contains the following code

```
<?php
namespace Module\Users;

class Users {
  public function test() { return "Testing hippie-yaay!"; }
}
```

The composer.json contains the following psr-0 autoload

```
"psr-0":{"Module\\": "application/"}
```

which in the autoloader_namespaces.php compiles to the following

```
'Module\\' => array($baseDir . '/application'),
```

Which then again, is totally correct (Ive tested this by echoing out the basedir -application string. It is totally correct.

now. In my main class i do the following

```
<?php
namespace System\Core;
use Module\Users\Users;

    class Initiater {
      public function bootSystem() {
        $u = new Users();
      }
    }
```

(this is basically what i do, ofcourse the other psr-0 autoloads i were talking about at the top are over this one, working just fine.)

I then get the following error.

> Fatal error: Class 'Module\Users\Users' not found in

FYI: I tried with just `"use Module\Users;"` and `"new \Module\Users\Users();"` both returning the same error.

I hope one of you knows whats going on here.
Best regards.
Jonas

Comment: What happens when you change your json to `"psr-0":{"Module": "application/"}`? Loose the trailing slash.

Comment: Case sensitivity checked? Class names are case insensitive, file names usually are case sensitive - and autoloading mixes the two. Make sure all your classnames are correctly written in file names and usage in the code.

Comment: "I am pulling my hairs out on this one" Instead of that, just debug it? Stick a break point in the ClassLoader::findFile function and look at what it's doing wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
new Users\Users();
```

is probably what you're looking for

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue. I did a "composer update" and it fixed my issue.
For some reason I had a namespace mismatch in the autoload_classmap.php

```
'Module' => $baseDir . '/application/Module/Users/Users.php',
```

and it was missing some info about the key part:

```
'Module\\Users' => $baseDir . '/application/Module/Users/Users.php',
```

So, like other mentioned, it's probably due to some invalid data that doesn't match your code.

Sometime you make a modification (like fixing a typo) and forgot to regenerate the autoloader and everything seems nice.

Answer (score 1):

If anyone is still having this problem: after digging into `ClassLoader.php`'s `findFileWithExtension()`, I found out that for me it was a case issue, like Sven mentioned. The class was named like `AbcTest`, while the file name was `ABCTest.php`. More generally, make sure that the file name matches the class name, case and all; it's just that case errors can be trickier to spot.